# query to laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

i am building a some of news website an i want to know how many sub categories there in a category. I build this query. (it works on my database) now i want i convert it to laravel query builder but i can't get it working.

**Raw query:**

```
   SELECT news_categories.id,
          news_categories.name,
          news_categories.description,
          count(nc.id)
     FROM happyalphen.news_categories 
LEFT JOIN news_categories nc ON nc.category_parent = news_categories.id 
    WHERE news_categories.category_parent = 0 
 GROUP BY news_categories.id ;
```

**what i have now**

```
DB::table('news_categories')
    ->selectRaw('news_categories.id')
    ->join('news_categories subCat', 'news_categories.category_parent', '=', 'subCat.id')
    ->where('news_categories.category_parent','=',0)
    ->groupBy('news_categories.id')
    ->get();
```

**Table layout**

[image: table layout]

Comment: Tell us why you can't get it working, otherwise nobody will care to help you prbably.. In this case: no need for `selectRaw`, simple `select` will do, and add `as` to alias table `join('news_categories as subCat' ..`

Comment: you seem to be left-joining `news_categories` to itself, or is it from another database on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it (Thanks Jarek Tkacyk)

i was forgot the 'AS' in the join that laravel stop with the query.

```
DB::table('news_categories')
   ->selectRaw(' `news_categories`.`id`, `news_categories`.`name`, `news_categories`.`description`, `news_categories`.`color`, `news_categories`.`text_color`, count(`SubCat`.`id`) as SubCatCount ')
   ->join('news_categories as subCat', 'subCat.category_parent', '=', 'news_categories.id','left')
   ->where('news_categories.category_parent','=','0')
   ->groupBy('news_categories.id')
   ->get();
```